# How to add metadata such as geokeydirectory, geoasciiparams, modelpixelscale and modeltiepoint to a compressed tiff image?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, digital-image-processing, matlab

I have resized my original tiff file (1.5gb) to a tiff file (170mb). But there was no geo reference points in the resized image which was present in my original tiff file. I have attached the screenshot which shows the geoinfo(co-ordinate points) of my original tiff file.

[image: georeferencing_tags_of_original_image]

I need the geo reference points\co-ordinate points to this resized image from my original tiif file. How do i add it?

I have coded my image resizing in "Matlab".
My code is as follows -

```
t = Tiff('D:\sample\a_01.tif','r'); 
imageData = read(t); 
Itrain = imresize(imageData,0.3); 
channel4 = Itrain(:,:,4); 
Itrain = Itrain(:,:, 1:3); 
scaled_train = mat2gray(Itrain); 
imwrite(scaled_train,'D:\com_1.tif')
```

Please do help me out!!

Comment: Please take a look at `geotiffwrite`: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html .

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger I appreciate your suggestion. But that did not help me. Because to include [A,R] values, "geotiffread" isn't reading my tiff file. And if i don't have [A,R] values i can't proceed with "geotiffwrite" function. So i wish if u could help me with alternate for geotiffread or any other suggestion is always welcomed.